# Torsion and divisible module

Tags: commutative-algebra, algebraic-number-theory

Let $R$ be an integral domain (Dedekind if necessary), and $M$ be a torsion divisible $R$-module. Can we say that $M$ is isomorphic to a direct sum of modules isomorphic to $K/R$, where $K$ is the fraction field of $R$.

Thanks @azif00 for the counterexample to the claim above (see his comment). Here I make $K$ a local field with residue field finite, $R$ the discrete valuation ring and $\pi$ a uniformizing element. Also we assume that the kernel of $\pi$ (the elements killed by $\pi$) has cardinality equal to that of the residue field, then can we say $M$ is isomorphic to $K/R$?

[image]

Comment: For a prime number $p$, the [Prüfer $p$-group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prüfer_group) is not isomorphic to a direct sum of copies of $\Bbb Q/\Bbb Z$. This is because of the [structure theorem of divisible groups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisible_group#Structure_theorem_of_divisible_groups).

Comment: That may be a counterexample. I'll supplement my question. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1):

I think I've found an answer to my question.

We construct a sequence $(x_i\in M)$ by: $x_0=0$ and $\pi x_i=x_{-1}$. Now define a map $K\rightarrow M$ by $\pi^{-i}a\mapsto a.x_i$, then the kernel is exactly $R$ and it is surjective. Hence $M\cong K/R$.